# Insert Data only once after Hibernate started

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, enums

I'm using hibernate 4.1.2

And I want insert some data into the table.

I know that it can be realized with sql in hibernate configuration in this way:
`<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files" value="/file1.sql,/file2.sql"/>`.

But, are there any other ways  insert automatically data  only once in Java code after hibernate started?

I want do it like this:

```
  public Role getRoleByName(EnumRole name) 
  {
    return (Role) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
    .createQuery("from Role where name   = :name")
    .setParameter("name", name).uniqueResult();
  }

 public void insertRoles(){
for(EnumRole role:EnumRole.values())
{
   Role r=getRoleByName(role);
   if(r==null)
   {
       r=new Role();
       r.setName(role);
       r.setDescription(role.getDescription());
       sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(r);
   }
}
```

EnumRole:

```
public enum EnumRole {

ROLE_CLIENT("РОЛЬ КЛИЕНТА"),
ROLE_ADMIN("РОЛЬ АДМИНСТРАТОРА"),
ROLE_CONSUMER("РОЛЬ КОМПАНЬОНА"),
ROLE_ANONYMOUS("НЕ АВТОРИЗОВАННЫЙ ПОЛЗОВАТЕЛЬ");

EnumRole(String descriptin)
{
    this.descriptin=descriptin;
}

public String getDescription()
{
    return this.descriptin;
}
private String descriptin;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create any Spring bean with `@PostConstruct` annotated method and for example create transaction using `PlatformTransactionManager`:

```
@Service
public class AnyBean  {
  @Autowired
  private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  @PostConstruct
  private void init() {
    TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
    transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<Object>() {
      @Override
      public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus transactionStatus) {
        // HERE YOU CODE
        for(EnumRole role:EnumRole.values())
        {
          Role r = getRoleByName(role);
          if(r==null)
          {
            r=new Role();
            r.setName(role);
            r.setDescription(role.getDescription());
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(r);
          }
        }            
        return null;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Create a service with method `insertRoles()` marked with `@Transactional` and call `service.insertRoles()`.
Or, more easy:

1. create a transaction
2. add roles
3. commit (or manage rollback if error occured)

Do this stuff after your application startup has been completed